# Couldn't retrieve customer_address_id from sales order (SOAP API)

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, soap-api-v2, customer-address

Im trying to get `customer_address_id` from `sales order` `address_id` in `shipping_address` and `billing_address`, but it doesn't match `customer_address_id`.

Is there any way to get `customer_address_id` based on sales order through SOAP API ?